# Operating System Error 123 On Backup of SQL Database Via Subprocess

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database-backups

I am currently attempting to backup a database automatically using a Python 3.7 application running the background. I managed to backup the database using the following query string.

```
SQLCommand = ("sqlcmd -E -S %s -Q \"BACKUP DATABASE %s TO DISK=\'%s\%02d-%02d-%02d-%02d:%02d:%02d.bak\'\"" % 
("MYSERVER\SQLSERVICE", "MyDatabase", 
"C:\\Users\Malek\Documents\PYSQLBS\Backups",
CDT.year, CDT.month, CDT.day, CDT.hour, CDT.minute, CDT.second))
...
print(subprocess.Popen(SQLCommand, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read())
```

However, I am getting this error. I am 100% sure that the folder `C:\Users\Malek\Documents\PYSQLBS\Backups` exists because I tested the command directly in the command line, and it worked perfectly.

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Server MYSERVER\SQLSERVICE, Line 1
>   Cannot open backup device 'C:\Users\Malek\Documents\PYSQLBS\Backups\2019-09
>       -09-16:24:46.bak'. Operating system error 123(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.).
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server MYSERVER\SQLSERVICE, 
>       Line 1
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Pls pay attention to what product tags you use! This question is about ms sql server, not mysql!

Comment: First thing you could do: hand in the command line as a list and not as a quoted sting. See the [subprocess docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) for many examples.

Comment: I believe that your problem is beacuse of the duplicated \-es, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Windows folder/file paths cannot contain `:` characters, except when delimiting the drive letter, e.g.: `C:\foo\bar.txt` is ok. `C:\foo\bar:::baz.txt` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `:` characters in your backup file's name: `2019-09 -09-16:24:46.bak`

Windows folder and file paths cannot contain `:` characters, except when delimiting the drive letter, e.g.: `C:\foo\bar.txt` is ok. `C:\foo\bar:::baz.txt` is not.

Comment: I see, I come from a Linux environment, and I have used : in my paths before as a habit. I will try it out, and report back (accept your answer hopefully).